# Netflix Vizceral Example error

Tags: node.js, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am trying to get the Netflix/Vizceral example going and get errors within the Vizceral.js file.

Example code ([from here](https://github.com/Netflix/vizceral/wiki/Getting-Started)):

```
import Vizceral from 'vizceral';
const viz = new Vizceral();

// Add event handlers for the vizceral events
viz.on('viewChanged', view => {});
viz.on('objectHighlighted', object => {});
viz.on('rendered', data => {});
viz.on('nodeContextSizeChanged', dimensions => {});
// ...

// Sample data
viz.updateData({
  name: 'us-west-2',
  renderer: 'global',
  nodes: [
    {name: 'INTERNET'},
    {name: 'service'}
  ],
  connections: [
    {
      source: 'INTERNET',
      target: 'service',
      metrics: { normal: 100, warning: 95, danger: 5 },
      metadata: { streaming: true }
    }
  ]
});
viz.setView();
viz.animate();
```

I am using the ES6 example. Error I receive is this:

> C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\vizceral.js:48717 var image =
>   document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'img' );
>                                                        ^
>
> ```
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> at ImageLoader.load (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\~\three\bui
> ld\three.js:30234:1)
> at TextureLoader.load (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\~\three\b
> uild\three.js:30380:1)
> at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\
> src\base\connectionView.js:32:8)
> at __webpack_require__ (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\webpack\
> bootstrap 2fc2dca69f7d99416dab:19:1)
> at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\vizceral.
> js:1105:24)
> at __webpack_require__ (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\webpack\
> bootstrap 2fc2dca69f7d99416dab:19:1)
> at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\vizceral.
> js:65:14)
> at __webpack_require__ (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\webpack\
> bootstrap 2fc2dca69f7d99416dab:19:1)
> at Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\webpack:\
> webpack\bootstrap 2fc2dca69f7d99416dab:39:1)
> at C:\Viz3\node_modules\vizceral\dist\vizceral.js:53:10
> ```

Comment: Is this in the browser?

Comment: This is in the Console I am trying to run it from.